# How to access Windows 8 Search api from Java?

Tags: java, winapi, windows-8, msdn, windows-api-code-pack

My java application should be able to list all the software from windows operating system and list result on its own java panel. For example if I type skype or any software name in my java application then it should search from windows os and list on java program and then should be able to open it. I don't know How to do this job and didn't find any example. I don't have any basic Idea of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: User can just press start button on keyboard, type skype and press enter

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying

Comment: I mean that your app is a little pointless since the shell already offers this exact functionality

Comment: does the shell offers this my applications features? if it is then could you please recommend any link?

Comment: What is the full extent of your program? Are you trying to make a "more intelligent" application launcher of some sort?

Comment: Now the given scenario is more specific, I think, now you will understand.

Comment: If the program to search for has a start menu or start screen entry, then typing into the start menu or start screen already will search for that program. If you're making a generic executable searching tool, then I don't know. And you still haven't said if you are making a more intelligent searcher than what Windows provides... That being said, here is the entry point to the [Windows Search API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Vista and newer only); hopefully that can help. Good luck. (This is beyond my personal expertise; sorry.)

Comment: Oh, and if this is an assignment to write a Start Menu searcher, then I don't know either - again, this is beyond my personal expertise - but there are other APIs (provided by the shell; see MSDN) that expose that information as well.